# Adding Verbosity to a Program

Tags: c++, c, linux, verbosity

This is  a very n00b question but 
I'm writing a nix based tool and would like to have verbosity flags, based on the number of vvv's passed in I would go about printing debug/information statements in my program.

My question is how would I go about using opargs for this, since optargs can only parse one character at a time.

Also suppose I know I'm at verbosity level 3, do all my print statements have to be in an if condition? Or there a clever way of going about it using the pre-processor?

Also if someone could point me to some code online which does this, that would be awesome.

Thanks

I figure it out, thought I'd post here if someone else comes across this in the future:

Basically for all my different verbosity statements I defined a special print using the preprocessor like:

```
#define dprintf \
    if (verbosity == 1) printf
```

I then put in the statements as needed in the code e.g.

```
dprintf ("Verbosity is at level 1.");
```

My opt atgs looks something like this

```
case 'v':
    verbosity++;
break;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use your option parsing mechanics with the string "-vvv"? Typically, this is handled as "-v -v -v" if there is such capability. Otherwise, you can always define three flags, "-v", "-vv" and "-vvv", and set the debug level using those. Either way, it's something of a small trick. But you only do it once.

Comment: then can I used the preprocessor to define a special "print" statement and use that to print out verbose options?

Comment: Why not just `-v1`, `-v2`, `-v3`, etc.?

Comment: Why not make use of some existing facilities like [`syslog`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) or [`Glib`'s logging mechanism](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Message-Logging.html)?

Answer (score 3):

The verbosity level is not known at compile time so you need to have code ready to handle any level the user selects.

A simple, and easy to understand, way of doing this is to separate your logging functions in an opaque compilation unit with a static variable keeping track of the verbosity level. You then initialize this with something like "set_logging_level(level)" and write your logging functions guarded by this static variable. Then you only expose the initialization and the logging functions and use them as you need them in your code.

```
static level = 0;
void set_logging_level(int l) { level = l; }

void log_info(char* msg) {
  // Will always print
}

void log_debug(char *msg) {
  if(level > 0)
    // Write to stdout or stderr, whichever fits
}

void log_details(char *msg) {
  if(level > 1)
    // As above
}

void log_insanity(char *msg) {
  if(level > 2)
    // As above
}
```

Edit: Saner conditions for logging. Especially if you want inclusive logging when the verbosity level goes up...

Comment: I would do this except using variadic functions and `vprintf`.  Or if for some reason you don't have a `vprintf`, you might still need to use a macro.  [The top google result for vprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/) has a good example.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Conditional compilation](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Conditional-Compilation.html)?

You could also simplify by setting a number for verbose level instead of passing that many *v's*.

```
#if VERBOSE_LEVEL == 3
  print("A verbose message");
#endif
```

Comment: I think he means the verbosity level is dictated by command line flags, which would make it a runtime test, rather than compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is what you've meant, but this is how I implemented it in another project:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

int usage( char *name, int quit );

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    static int vlevel = 0;

    while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, ":abc:d:hv012")) != -1) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        switch (c) {

            case 'v':
                vlevel++;
                printf ("verbosity level is %d\n", vlevel);
                break;

            case ':':       /* Option without required operand */
                fprintf(stderr, "option -%c requires an operand\n", optopt);
                break;

            case 'h':
            case '?':
                usage( argv[0], TRUE );
                break;

            default:
                printf ("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
        }
    }

    if (optind < argc) {
        printf ("non-option ARGV-elements:\n");
        while (optind < argc)
            printf ("\t%s\n", argv[optind++]);
    }

    exit (0);
}

int usage( char *progname, int quit )
{
    printf ( "Usage:\n\t%s [-vh]\n", progname );
    if ( quit ) exit( 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

This would give you something like the following:

```
eroux@smaug:~$ ./testverbose -h
Usage:
    ./testverbose [-vh]
eroux@smaug:~$ ./testverbose -vvvv
verbosity level is 1
verbosity level is 2
verbosity level is 3
verbosity level is 4
eroux@smaug:~$
```

From there you should be able to use the vlevel variable [in main()] to print the correct message during the relevant verbosity level.